# Rails: how do I validate that something is a boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Does rails have a validator like `validates_numericality_of` for boolean or do I need to roll my own?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Since Rails 3, you can do:

```
validates :field, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ] }
```

Comment: So, this gets the validation right, but the error message is not helpful for the end user: "myfield is not included in the list"

Comment: Good point. You can customize the error message: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#message

Comment: Shorter form `validates :field, inclusion: [true, false]`

Comment: Note that you cannot have the usual validation for the presence (`validates :field, presence: true`) for a boolean field (the field would not be valid for a `false` value). But in both Rails 3 and 4, having `validates :field, inclusion: [true, false]` would test for inclusion in a list of values, with the side-effect to test for the field's presence (unless one of those values is `nil` of course).

Comment: And for those who need it with an error-message:
`validates :field, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ], message: "Please, select one!" }`

Comment: But this does not validate if the field is assigned with a string value. Say `'True'` or `'Some value'`. These string values are definitely not boolean. But validation does not fail for these. Any updates on this?

Comment: @SriramK89, from what I saw on a [Medium post](https://medium.com/@mikeappell/rails-presence-validations-booleans-and-pain-1b04adb111ab#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20validate,handles%20boolean%20values%3A%20false.), it seems you have to develop your own custom validator. It seems Rails will always try to cast other values into a boolean if that field is a boolean.

Answer (score 43):

I believe for a boolean field you will need to do something like:

```
validates_inclusion_of :field_name, :in => [true, false]
```

From an older version of the [API](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M001821&name=validates_presence_of): "This is due to the way Object#blank? handles boolean values. false.blank? # => true"

I'm not sure if this will still be fine for Rails 3 though, hope that helped!

Comment: lol @ Rails 3. I can bet this will be the caveat for months to come. Ok, I thought this migth have been it and you agree. Thanks!

Comment: It's true for Rails 4! Wow, false.blank? # => true just seems like the *wrong* answer, something I would not expect from Rails.

Comment: This does not work, as any string eg, "foo" will be converted into `true`.

Answer (score 15):

When I apply this, I get:

Warning from shoulda-matchers:

You are using `validate_inclusion_of` to assert that a boolean column
allows boolean values and disallows non-boolean ones. Be aware that it
is not possible to fully test this, as boolean columns will
automatically convert non-boolean values to boolean ones. Hence, you
should consider removing this test.

Comment: For fields where null is allowed, does it still convert nil to boolean?

Comment: Just remove that test, except if column is nullable you should do this:

it { should allow_value(nil).for(:field) }

[Reference](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveModel:validate_inclusion_of)

Comment: The link in the above comment is broken, but here's a working link: http://matchers.shoulda.io/docs/v4.4.1/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel.html#validate_inclusion_of-instance_method

Answer (score 6):

You can use the shorter version:

```
validates :field, inclusion: [true, false]
```

Extra thought. When dealing with enums, I like to use a constant too:

```
KINDS = %w(opening appointment).freeze

enum kind: KINDS

validates :kind, inclusion: KINDS
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer according to [Rails Docs 5.2.3](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

This helper (presence) validates that the specified attributes are not empty. It uses the blank? method to check if the value is either nil or a blank string, that is, a string that is either empty or consists of whitespace.

Since false.blank? is true, if you want to validate the presence of a boolean field you should use one of the following validations:

```
validates :boolean_field_name, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

Comment: This the same answer as a previous one except the updated documents reflect the fact that hash rockets are no longer necessary. +1.