# Rails model default_value method conflict with presence true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this simplified model:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user   belongs_to :plan

  before_validation :set_default_is_voided   
  before_validation :set_default_expiration

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :plan, presence: true
  validates :contract_date, presence: true
  validates :is_voided, presence: true
  validates :expiration, presence: true

  protected

  def set_default_is_voided
    if self.is_voided.nil?
      self.is_voided = false
      ap self.is_voided.present?
      ap self.is_voided
    end
  end

  def set_default_expiration
    if self.contract_date.present?
      self.expiration = self.contract_date+1.month
    end
  end

end
```

And this rspec simplified test:

```
context "Should create default values" do
  it "Have to create is_voided" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    plan = FactoryGirl.create(:planContract)
    ap "HERE"
    contractDefault = FactoryGirl.create(:contractDefault, plan: plan, user: user)
    ap contractDefault
    expect(contractDefault.is_voided).to eq(false)
  end
  it "Have to create expiration" do
    #expect(contract.expiration).should eq(Date.today()+1.month)
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :contractVoid, class:Contract do
  end
  factory :contractDefault, class:Contract do
    contract_date Date.today
  end
end
```

This test fail with an 'is_voided can't be blank'.

And the question is:
Why the method "set_default_is_voided" in before_validation don't pass the presence true validation? Moreover, the self.is_voided.present? return false, why is it happing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question as to why `set_default_is_voided` doesn't pass the the `presence: true` validation, namely that `self.is_voided.present?` returns `false`, which is how `presence: true` is determined.

`self.is_voided.present?` returns `false` because `false.present? == false` per [A concise explanation of nil v. empty v. blank in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885414/a-concise-explanation-of-nil-v-empty-v-blank-in-ruby-on-rails)

See [Rails: how do I validate that something is a boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608076/rails-how-do-i-validate-that-something-is-a-boolean) for one way to validate that a boolean field is not `nil`.

See http://www.quora.com/Why-does-Rails-make-false-blank-true for a Q&A on the motivation behind the definition of `blank?`.