# .sample not working in seeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

The variable `var` is a `boolean` and should not be allowed to be blank. Therefore in my model file I have:

```
validates_inclusion_of :var, :in => [true, false]
validates :var, presence: true
```

In my seeds file I have:

```
title = "abc"
var = [true, false].sample
author.articles.create!( title: title,
                         var: var)
```

Seeding produces the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Var can't be blank
```

Does anyone understand why it wants to create an article with a blank var?

**Update:** Using the `debugger`, I can confirm that var had a value of 1.

Schema for articles:

```
  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "title",          limit: 50,                null: false
    t.boolean  "var",                       default: true, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                               null: false
  end
```

Comment: I also tried `var = [0, 1].sample` but that made no difference. I use `.sample` at other locations of seeds as well, without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should not be allowed to be blank

A better way will be to set a `default` value in the db.

Not only will this free up Rails processing power, but will also make sure that no matter what, that value *has* to be present, a necessity for `boolean`:

```
$ rails g migration AddDefaultToBool

# db/migrate/add_default_to_bool____________.rb
class AddDefaultToBool < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_column :articles, :var, :boolean, default: false
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This way, you'll always have the `boolean` as `false` if the value is not present. I know it's not specifically what you're asking, but will be a better solution anyway.

---

In terms of your validation, you'll want to use the newer [`validates`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers) shorthand:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :var, presence: true, inclusion: [:true, :false]
end
```

According to comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608076/rails-how-do-i-validate-that-something-is-a-boolean), you shouldn't have `presence` for a `boolean` value:

> Note that you cannot have the usual validation for the presence (`validates :field, presence: true`) for a `boolean field` (the field would not be valid for a false value).
>
> But in both Rails 3 and 4, having `validates :field, inclusion: [true, false]` would test for inclusion in a list of values, with the side-effect to test for the field's presence (unless one of those values is nil of course). – Martin Carel Jul 14 at 19:38

... so you *should* be able to use the following:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :var, inclusion: [:true, :false]
end
```

[Another good ref](http://brettu.com/rails-daily-ruby-tips-122-dont-validates-presence-of-rails-boolean-fields/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Explaining is one thing, getting it working is another :) Would be interested to know if it works or not

Comment: I actually got it to work by removing the line `validates :var, presence: true`. As it turns out `presence` is not an allowed validation for booleans.